# Updating large DataFrame objects not on disk.

Tags: python, pandas, csv, hdf5, large-data

I've been learning the ins and outs of Pandas by way of manipulating large csv files obtained online, the files are time-series of financial data. I have so far figured out how to use HDFStore to store and manipulate them, however I was wondering if there exists an easier way to update the files, without re-downloading the entire source file?

I ask because I'm working with 12 ~300+MB files, which update every 15mins. While I don't need the update to be continuous it'd be swell to not download what I already have.

Comment: can you be more specific what you are trying to update? pls show some code as well

Comment: Can you only download the bits you want and then append to the existing data frame? This sounds like more of an issue with your data source and not so much a Pandas question. Maybe you could clarify.

Comment: it looks like what ur talking about is streaming which is not built in to pandas (yet?)...

Comment: This question is not going to be answered in current form without interaction from questioner

Answer (score 1):

The [Blaze](http://blaze.pydata.org/docs/latest/index.html) library from [Continuum](http://continuum.io) should help you. You can find an introduction [here](http://continuum.io/blog/blaze-expressions).